# Return camel routes configuration to xml

Tags: java, apache-camel

I was wondering if it was possible to return all or part of routes from camel context - I'd like to make the configuration using Java and then to retrieve it to export it to xml.

Is there a way to achieve that? I haven't found anything in documentation and I hope I just missed something and there is a way.

Comment: Not sure I understand, you want to configure the route in the java dsl but export it using blueprint xml? I don't think you can do this directly. You can do it if you install hawtio and run the camel routes inside hawtio. Then login and view the routes and it shows them in the xml format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and what you are looking for is this JMX MBean interface:
http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/api/management/mbean/ManagedCamelContextMBean.html#dumpRoutesAsXml()

Basically JMX is enabled by default in Camel, so you can just connect to the JVM running Camel using a JMX console like JConsole. Then track down the CamelContext MBean like `org.apache.camel:context=...,type=context,name=...` and invoke the operation `dumpRoutesAsXml()`. And you'll get all the routes in the Camel context as XML.

For more information on Camel and JMX, you may refer to this documentation as well:
http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html

Comment: To access ManagedCamelContextMBean, you could use : camelContext.getExtension(ManagedCamelContext.class).getManagedCamelContext()
     .dumpRoutesAsXml();

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
    List<RouteDefinition> routes = camelContext.getRouteDefinitions();
    RoutesDefinition def = new RoutesDefinition();
    def.setRoutes(routes);
    String xml = ModelHelper.dumpModelAsXml(camelContext, def);
```

If you want the property place holders to be replaced, refer to the method  ManagedCamelContext.dumpRoutesAsXml

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Your question is still not clear.

But there are 2 options for you.

1. Blueprint containers accept hot deployments, meaning you can just drop the Camel XML in a folder and it will just start the route. It also depends on the kind of system you are trying to integrate with, For eg: doing this for database related integration is bit complex.
2. You can use route builder, basically you can create routes during run time and start a route.

Please post more details around your question, to understand better. You may not even need both approach, if you can explain your requirement clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hawtio for managing camel routes and you can see routes on their xml form, here I wrote my routes on java dsl and can see their xml forms
[image]

Or you can dump route as xml [image]